# Ember Component Integration Tests: `link-to` href empty

Tags: javascript, ember.js, integration-testing, htmlbars

I'm trying to write a component integration test, a la [this blog post](http://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/ember-component-integration-tests/), but my component has a `link-to` to a dynamic route and the `href` property isn't being filled in. Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do.

My component's template:

```
{{#link-to "myModel" model}}
```

And here is the relevant part of my test:

```
this.set('model', {
  id: 'myId',
  name: 'My Name'
});

this.render(hbs`
{{my-component model=model}}
`);

assert.equal(this.$('a').attr('href'), '/myModel/myId'); // fails
```

The `link-to` is rendered, just without an `href` attribute. If I log the HTML in the test, it looks like:

```
<a id="ember283" class="ember-view">My Name</a>
```

Is there something I need to do to my "model" to get the `link-to` to have an href? I tried to look at the tests for `link-to` in ember, and found [this part of the tests](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/9af8d2193804baf3c280687c77ffc35de1e2e994/packages/ember/tests/helpers/link_to_test.js#L510,), which is basically what I'm doing – provide a POJO with the `id` key set. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.13.8
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.13.10
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.3
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Comment: Is it integration test or unit test?

Comment: @Daniel: integration test

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out you can just look up the router and tell it to start routing in your test setup and it will work. From [this commit](https://github.com/rwjblue/cast/commit/9dc6fd92c600834a0556183760cf9007be509e05) from @rwjblue:

```
// tests/helpers/setup-router.js

export default function({ container }) {
  const router = container.lookup('router:main');
  router.startRouting(true);
}


// tests/integration/components/my-component-test.js

import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';
import setupRouter from '../../helpers/setup-router';

moduleForComponent('my-component', 'Integration | Component | my component', {
  integration: true,
  setup() {
    setupRouter(this);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I could now see the `href`, but another error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'didCreateRootView' of undefined` prevents the test from passing

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to do it in Ember > 3

```
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { setupRenderingTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import { render } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

module('Integration | Component | my-component', function (hooks) {
  setupRenderingTest(hooks);

  test('it has a link', async function (assert) {
    this.owner.lookup('router:main').setupRouter();
    await render(hbs`{{my-component}}`);
    assert.equal(this.element.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href'), 'some-url');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to check the `href` is ok, it  could be better use `setupRouter` instead of `startRouting`. `startRouting` tries to handle the initial transition to the initial URL, and that could be problematic.

```js
// tests/helpers/setup-router.js
export default function({ container }) {
 const router = container.lookup('router:main');
 router.setupRouter();
}
```

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/d487061228a966d8aac6fa94a8d69abfc3f1f257/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L202

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ember are you using? I remember seeing this previously and now it seems to work in my app (though I'm using 1.13.8).

Seems to be adding the href's in my application, and based on [this computed property](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/ae6c9e82b91fd5b695907e7b76c998a128a157d0/packages/ember-routing-views/lib/views/link.js#L338) it should be bound to the view if the `tagName` is "a".

Other than upgrading Ember, it's probably best to create an ember-fiddle or repro and file a bug if it persists.

You may also want to take a look at https://github.com/intercom/ember-href-to.

Comment: I added Ember version info to the question (I am on 1.13.8 also), and have no problem with the `href`'s getting added in my application – they are only missing in the test.